# Spellchecking Japanese Queries in Solr 9.0.0

Tags: solr, lucene, spell-checking

I'm trying to implement a spellchecker in Solr 9.0.0 that supports Japanese queries, but I couldn't find specific documentation on how to achieve this. I've attempted to modify the default spellchecker configuration in the `solrconfig.xml` file to work with Japanese fields, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Can someone guide me on how to spellcheck Japanese queries in Solr 9.0.0?

Here's the default configuration in the `solrconfig.xml` file:

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
  <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
</searchComponent>

<spellchecker name="default_sc" class="solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker">
  <str name="field">name</str>
</spellchecker>
```

I have a Japanese field called `name_ja`, which uses the `text_ja` field type. I attempted to modify the default spellchecker configuration to support Japanese by changing the `queryAnalyzerFieldType` to `text_ja` and adding a new spellchecker for the `name_ja` field. However, it doesn't seem to work, I don't get any errors but the spellchecker doesn't return any suggestions.

I modified the `solrconfig.xml` to something like this:

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
  <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_ja</str>
</searchComponent>

<spellchecker name="japanese_sc" class="solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker">
  <str name="field">name_ja</str>
</spellchecker>
```

Are there any specific spellchecker classes or configuration parameters that need to be used for Japanese language support? Any examples or code snippets would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In addition to updating the `searchComponent` for the spell checker you also need to update the `<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">` to use the searchComponent. Here is an example of how this is configured https://github.com/hectorcorrea/solr-for-newbies/blob/main/tutorial.md#spellchecker (This is for a field in English, I am not sure if there are differences for fields in Japanese.) Do you have a working example in English that you are trying to convert or is this your first attempt?

Comment: To clarify, I use `/spell` `requestHandler` like the example does for `/select`. I get the spellchecker working but only for english. The japanese implementation doesn't give any results back from the spellchecker.